# How to enable claimrewards for eosio?

Tags: eosio.system

I have a test net. There are 5 producers. When I try claim rewards. It report

```
sam@sam-machine:~/Public/oasis-eos/oasis$ cleos --wallet-url "http://127.0.0.1:8905" system claimrewards producer1111 -p producer1111
Error 3090004: Missing required authority
Ensure that you have the related authority inside your transaction!;
If you are currently using 'cleos push action' command, try to add the relevant authority using -p option.
Error Details:
missing authority of eosio.token
pending console output:
```

I see the difference between the mainnet and mine about the authority "eosio". "eosio.token".

```
sam@sam-machine:~/Public/eos$ cleos get account eosio
privileged: true
permissions:
     owner     1:    1 EOS56epkkpVdmZ49UhSKJagh5F6qgBeEFkHyL25Z2Z1a4SeUqRbm7
        active     1:    1 EOS56epkkpVdmZ49UhSKJagh5F6qgBeEFkHyL25Z2Z1a4SeUqRbm7
memory:
     quota:       unlimited  used:     1.118 MiB

net bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited


sam@sam-machine:~/Public/eos$ cleos get account eosio.token
permissions:
     owner     1:    1 EOS7qpzrhBgaMmcoucqSyDb4pNnyVCPn81c1PVsUJMwD5c6tV2FYf
        active     1:    1 EOS7qpzrhBgaMmcoucqSyDb4pNnyVCPn81c1PVsUJMwD5c6tV2FYf
memory:
     quota:       unlimited  used:     191.3 KiB

net bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

producers:
     laidao111111    producer1111    producer2222
     producer3333    producer4444    producer5555
```

But for mainnet:

```
sam@mainnet:~$ cleos get account eosio
privileged: true
permissions:
     owner     1:    1 eosio.prods@active,
        active     1:    1 eosio.prods@active,
memory:
     quota:       unlimited  used:      33.1 MiB

net bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

EOS balances:
     liquid:            6.2257 EOS
     staked:            0.0000 EOS
     unstaking:         0.0000 EOS
     total:             6.2257 EOS



sam@mainnet:~$ cleos get account eosio.token
permissions:
     owner     1:    1 eosio@active,
        active     1:    1 eosio@active,
memory:
     quota:     212.8 KiB    used:     212.8 KiB

net bandwidth:
     used:                 0 bytes
     available:            0 bytes
     limit:                0 bytes

cpu bandwidth:
     used:              1.62 ms
     available:            0 us
     limit:                0 us

EOS balances:
     liquid:         3735.1607 EOS
     staked:            0.0000 EOS
     unstaking:         0.0000 EOS
     total:          3735.1607 EOS
```

So what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that because the `claim` command belongs to the `eosio` smart contract, and the `eosio` contract is then calling for a transfer using `eosio.token` smart contract through an inline action, it is required that the `eosio.token` contract have the same permission as the `eosio` contract does.

So if you replicate the permission structure that you describe on the mainnet, this problem will resolve itself.

Answer (score -1):

Check that you had unlocked the producer1111 active key in your keosd wallet

Comment: I have checked. It reports "missing authority of eosio.token"

Answer (score -1):

First check your wallet.

- if wallet is unlocked
- if producer111's private key is imported

Second check if producer produced block.

```
$cleos get table eosio eosio producers


 "rows": [{
      {
      "owner": "producer111",
      ...  some information
      "unpaid_blocks": 1032,  // this!
      ...  some information
    },{
```

Note that producer can claimrewards per one day.

Comment: 1 wallet have been unlocked
2 producer1111 is one of the producer. Actually, all producers can not claim rewards.

Comment: @sam look at command output, producer can earn ("unpaid_block" X blahblah)

check your nodeos log, you can see "signed by <producer" ..
if there "signed by eosio" now?  BOOT is not complete.

Comment: "owner": "producer1111", "unpaid_blocks": 1729585,

Comment: Sorry for the limit of comment length.

Comment: so difficult TT

Can you show me following two command's output? :)
1. cleos key list
2. cleos get account producer1111 |grep active

Comment: sam@sam-machine:~/Public/oasis-eos/oasis$ cleos get account producer1111 | grep active
        active     1:    1 EOS5pvVoggbJjrq6HErKiW1Bz9uaXokW2tAyhCv8wycdjeLXYNCkv
sam@sam-machine:~/Public/oasis-eos/oasis$

Comment: sam@sam-machine:~/Public/oasis-eos/oasis$ cleos --wallet-url "http://127.0.0.1:8905" wallet list keys
Wallets:
[
  "sam *"
]
  "EOS5pvVoggbJjrq6HErKiW1Bz9uaXokW2tAyhCv8wycdjeLXYNCkv",

Comment: Hm, It's so weird. I can't figure out the cause. 
I had try to build environment like yours. But There's no problem.

Comment: Can I see your 'cleos get account eosio.token'? Is it a multisig?

Comment: I had test both eosio@active and normal key to eosio.token's key. But There's no wallet error.

Answer (score -1):

Think is just the "@active" part of the permission missing. 
Shoudn't it be:

cleos --wallet-url "http://127.0.0.1:8905" system claimrewards producer1111 -p producer1111@active